# Can someone please explain how can I find the winner of each game in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

So I'm supposed to find the winners from {P1: N1, P2: N2} where N1 and N2 are the number of games player P1 and player P2 win in the match, I have to write a function `winner(records: List[Dict[str,int]])` that takes a list of all match records and returns the name of the tournament winner.

The tournament winner is determined as the player **with the most wins** from each input.

Also, The function should return a string `-` if it cannot determine the winner.

Example

```
assert winner([{'A':2,'B':1}]) == 'A'
assert winner([{'A':3,'B':0},{'A':1,'C':2}]) == '-'
assert winner([{'A':3,'B':0},{'A':1,'C':2},{'B':0,'C':3}]) == 'C'
assert winner([{'A':3,'B':0},{'A':1,'C':2},{'B':0,'D':3},{'A':2,'D':1}]) == 'A'
assert winner([{'A':3,'B':0},{'B':2,'C':1},{'C':2,'D':1},{'A':0,'D':3}]) == '-'
```

Here is my attempt at the code so far...

```
def finder(records):
    for x in winners:
        return max(x, key = x.get)
def winner(records):
    for x in finder(records):
        if x.count == max(x.count):
           return x
        else:
           return '-'
```

But it doesn't really work... what changes to my code should I make??

Comment: 'But it doesn't really work' is insufficient as an explanation of what doesn't work.  Do you get an error, do you get incorrect results, Do you get some correct results and some incorrect results? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting your code a bit, this should give the desired results:

```
def winner(records):
    winners={} # dictionary to keep players and number of wins
    
    for x in records:       
        maxplayer= max(x,key=x.get) # find winner player
        # update dict of winners
        if maxplayer in winners:
            winners[maxplayer]+=1
        else:
            winners.update({maxplayer:1})
    
    maxpoints=max(winners.values()) # find total points winner(s)
    
    # if more than 1 player with max points is a tie 
    if list(winners.values()).count(maxpoints)>1:
        return "-"
    else:
        return max(winners, key=winners.get)
```